# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_3 to have shape (1,58,58), but got array with shape (1,64,64)

Tags: python, keras

I am new to Keras and I am trying to make a comparison between Sequential and functional classifications using images(64x64, 1 channel), this is my model(sequential):

```
x_pos_train = x_pos[int(x_pos.shape[0]* .20):] #shape(20,1,64,64)
x_pos_test = x_pos[:int(x_pos.shape[0]* .20)] #shape(5,1,64,64)
x_pos_noisy = x_pos_train + 0.05 * np.random.normal(loc=0., scale=1., size=x_pos_train.shape) #(20, 1, 64, 64)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras import backend as K  #image dim ordering in conv2d won't work
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

seqmodel = Sequential()

seqmodel.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(1,64,64)))
seqmodel.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

seqmodel.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'))
seqmodel.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

seqmodel.add(Conv2D(1, (3,3), activation='sigmoid'))

seqmodel.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy') 
seqmodel.fit(x_pos_noisy,
         x_pos_train,
         epochs=10,
         batch_size=32,
         shuffle=True,
         validation_split=.20)
```

x_pos is an array of images reshaped for keras (channels, rows, cols)

The source is here: [How to denoise images with neural networks](https://hub.packtpub.com/how-to-denoise-images-neural-networks/).

The problem is that when I run it, it throws an error at seqmodel.fit:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_3 to have shape (1,58,58), but got array with shape (1,64,64)
```

Since the original code wasn't working, I've made a few changes to fit my needs.

**Edit 1:**

[Sequential Summary Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBkA4.png)

I know that the target(x_pos_train) is different from the output layer, but I want to know why is this happening, since the code is supposed to work.

Comment: Have a look at `seqmodel.summary()` and take note of the last layer shape, then `print(x_pos_train.shape)` you'l notice it is what the error says.

Comment: You missed mentioning `padding='same'` in the second and third convolutional layer

Comment: @Ashar7 That worked! omg, this never crossed my mind. Thank you very much. Maybe something has changed on the newer version of keras, because I adapted the code, and the source code didn't have it.

Comment: @MACACO94 Yeah just keep in mind to check your model summary first if any errors are related to input's or output's shapes.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer to help other people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Since your third convolutional layer expects an array of size (1, 64, 64) you have to use 'same' padding in the layers which are shrinking the size of your input (second and third convolutional layer in this case) to restrict them from changing the input array's size.
So, the code will look like this:

```
seqmodel = Sequential()

seqmodel.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(1,64,64)))
seqmodel.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

seqmodel.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
seqmodel.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

seqmodel.add(Conv2D(1, (3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
```